# Как найти введённый текст в textarea во всех div-ах на странице и вывести результат "Текст найден" в другой textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня на html странице есть много div-ов и два textarea, в первый нужно ввести текст, а второй должен менять своё value на "Такой текст есть на странице" в том случае, если внутри всех div-ов на странице есть введённый текст. В противном случае - оставлять второй textarea пустым. Подразумеваю выполнение функции прямо во время ввода в textarea, т.е. ивент oninput. Как это можно реализовать на ванильном js?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Приложите код, с помощью которого вы пытались реализовать задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div')
const search = document.getElementById('search')

search.addEventListener('input', () => {
  let findedDivs = Array.from(divs).filter(item => item.innerText.includes(search.value))
  console.log(findedDivs)
})
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">Какой-то текст</div>
<div class="div">То, что ищем</div>
<div class="div"></div>
<textarea id="search" placeholder="Что ищем"></textarea>
```